# Trying to reshape a large stacked csv file into a panel data format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, panel-data

I have some data loaded in python with pandas. I also have the following data frame structure

```
Country Year Subject Value
‘USA’   1991  ‘GDP’  NUM1
‘USA’   1992  ‘GDP’  NUM2
‘USA’   1993  ‘GDP’  NUM3
‘USA’   1991  ‘INV’  NUM4
‘USA’   1992  ‘INV’  NUM5
‘USA’   1993  ‘INV’  NUM6
```

I want to turn this format into this more standard panel data structure

```
Country Year   GDP   INV
‘USA’   1991  NUM1  NUM4
‘USA’   1992  NUM2  NUM5
‘USA’   1993  NUM3  NUM6
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
df:

Country Year    Subject Value
0   USA 1991    GDP     10
1   USA 1992    GDP     20
2   USA 1993    GDP     30
3   USA 1991    INV     40
4   USA 1992    INV     50
5   USA 1993    INV     60
```

You need [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```
pv = df.pivot_table(index=['Country', 'Year'], columns=['Subject'], values=['Value']).reset_index()
pv.columns = [col[0] if col[1]=='' else col[1] for col in pv.columns.values ]
```

Output:

```
    Country Year    GDP INV
0   USA     1991    10  40
1   USA     1992    20  50
2   USA     1993    30  60
```